# Wordpress only load after <!--more--> contents using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress  posts structures  are like this

```
From nd mobiles. Get the best theme mockups on the market.
<!--more-->    
Investigationes demonstraverunt<strong> lectores legere</strong> 
me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est
```

I shows post content before "more" tag on my home page, 
and trying to load after "more" contents separately via ajax, 
i wrote some codes but it restuns full post, 
but i only need to return after part of "more" tag

ex

```
Investigationes demonstraverunt<strong> lectores legere</strong> 
    me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est
```

only this part my code for get contents via ajax is

```
<div id="single-post post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
         <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile;?>      
    </div>
```

this give full post anyone know how to get only contents after the  "more" tag
Thank You